# DXA 1.6 ROOT.war not working on Tomcat 8

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.6

I have deployed the DXA 1.6 "Web 8, Live" `ROOT.war` to Tomcat and it fails.

The key error in the Tomcat log is this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/tld/TldParser
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.(TldScanner.java:84)

The odd thing is that the “Staging” build of the webapp works fine.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: What's your Tomcat exact version?

Comment: Hi - I had been using 8.0. I installed 8.5 and it worked. I hadn't realised that there was a different version on my staging server where things were working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was the Tomcat version that was cuasing the problem.